# How to test Gmail OTP verification with Appium. I want to do OTP verification by appium can any one help me?

Tags: java, selenium, appium, nativeapplication

I can get the OTP from gmail but i don't know how to enter the OTP into the mobile application?
What is the best way of approach to handle gmail otp into mobile application?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can find the OTP input box using Appium specific locator and do `sendKeys` on that element to input the OTP you have got in Email. This should be straight forward if you know Selenium WebDriver.

To find the OTP input locator, you can use [Appium inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/releases).

Hope this answers your question.